# build an NSArray from nsarray already exist

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsarray, nsdictionary

i have an NSArray with JsonValue from my webservice.

```
myArray = [responseString JSONValue];
```

this Array give me that in a NSLog:

```
 2012-02-18 18:22:46.338 Test[2758:fb03] myArray: (
            {
            receiver = david;
            sender = sophie;
            message = "test1";
            photo = "****************.jpg";
        },
            {
            receiver = david;
            sender = matt;
            message = "test2";
            photo = "****************.jpg";
        },
            {
            receiver = sophie;
            sender = mike;
            message = "test1";
            photo = "****************.jpg";
        },
            {
            receiver = david;
            sender = ali;
            message = "test1";
            photo = "****************.jpg";
        },
            {
            receiver = mike;
            sender = david;
            message = "test1";
            photo = "****************.jpg";
        },
            {
            receiver = admin;
            sender = david;
            message = "test1";
            photo = "****************.jpg";
        }
    )
```

I need to create a new array with only sender = 'David'

i try with that:

```
for(int i=0;i<[myArray count];i++)
   {
    NSDictionary *dict1=[myArray objectAtIndex:i];


       if ( [[dict1 objectForKey:@"sender"] isEqualToString:@"david"]) 


       {

           NSLog(@"YES");


           myNewArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dict1, nil];

            NSLog(@"array %@",myNewArray);
            NSLog(@"count %d",[myNewArray count]);



       }
       else
       {
           NSLog(@"NO");


           myNewArray2 = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:dict1, nil];

            NSLog(@"array2 %@",myNewArray2);
            NSLog(@"count2 %d",[myNewArray2 count]);
       }
   }
```

this myNewArray give me that:

```
           2012-02-18 18:22:46.341 Test[2758:fb03] myNewArray (
        {
            receiver = mike;
            sender = david;
            message = "test1";
            photo = "****************.jpg";
    }
)
          2012-02-18 18:22:46.341 Test[2758:fb03] myNewArray (
        {
            receiver = admin;
            sender = david;
            message = "test1";
            photo = "****************.jpg";
    }
)
```

But i need to have a array like that:

```
2012-02-18 18:22:46.338 Test[2758:fb03] myNewArray: (

        {
            receiver = mike;
            sender = david;
            message = "test1";
            photo = "****************.jpg";
    },
        {
            receiver = admin;
            sender = david;
            message = "test1";
            photo = "****************.jpg";
    }
)
```

thx for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A NSArray is immutable, you will need a NSMutableArray. And you are re-initliazing the new array on every loop, which you cannot do if you want to keep the previous values.

```
NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {
    NSDictionary *m = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];

    if ([[m objectForKey:@"sender"] isEqualToString:@"david"]) {
        [a addObject:m];
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a much easier way. Try using NSArray's `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` where the predicate in your case is something like this:

```
NSString *attribute = @"sender";
NSString *senderFilter = @"david";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@", attribute, senderFilter];

NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

For more details on predicates, try the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html).

Comment: thx for for your post. so i use filteredArrayUsingPredicate and i get myArray but my app crash when i use  NSDictionary *dico2 = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; error :objectatindex index 1 beyond bounds 0 0. myArray is not empty but somewhere before cellForRowAtIndexPath have to be call the array look like empty

Comment: i have the same error in cellForRowAtIndexPath when i use this: NSDictionary * dicos = [myNewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Answer (score 1):

Declare  `myNewArray` outside of the cycle, and make it a NSMutableArray (it'll allow to add new objects )

```
myNewArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] array];
for(int i=0;i<[myArray count];i++)
{
    ...
}
```

then add object to this array if some condition is equal

```
NSLog(@"YES");
[myNewArray addObject:dict1];
```